# Unexpected metaclass overriding for the DRF serializers

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, metaclass

I'm using Django 1.11.12 and djangorestframework==3.7.7 and python3.6.3

I have several models inherited from one abstract model:

```
class SoftDeleteModel(models.Model):
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

And there are a dozens of models inherited from it. I need this deleted field to be shown only for the admin user.

Trying not to repeat the same logic again and again I wrote a metaclass and abstract class to make things easier to handle in the serializers. Most parts of the custom metaclass are from serializers.SerializerMetaclass.

```
class SoftDeletionMetaclass(serializers.SerializerMetaclass):

    @classmethod
    def _get_declared_fields(cls, bases, attrs):
        fields = [(field_name, attrs.pop(field_name))
                for field_name, obj in list(attrs.items())
                if isinstance(obj, Field)]
        fields.append(("deleted", serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)))
        fields.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]._creation_counter)
        # If this class is subclassing another Serializer, add that Serializer's
        # fields.  Note that we loop over the bases in *reverse*. This is necessary
        # in order to maintain the correct order of fields.
        for base in reversed(bases):
            if hasattr(base, '_declared_fields'):
                fields = [
                    (field_name, obj) for field_name, obj
                    in base._declared_fields.items()
                    if field_name not in attrs
                ] + fields
        return OrderedDict(fields)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['_declared_fields'] = cls._get_declared_fields(bases, attrs)
        meta = attrs.get('Meta')
        if meta:
            if isinstance(meta.fields, tuple):
                meta.fields += ("deleted", )
            else:
                meta.fields.append("deleted")
            attrs["Meta"] = meta
        return super(serializers.SerializerMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

And I wrote an abstract serializer which use this metaclass

```
class SoftDeletionSerializer(metaclass=SoftDeletionMetaclass):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Not Admin user shouldn't see deleted field
        if (not self.context.get("request") or not hasattr(self.context.get("request"), 'user')
            or not self.context.get("request").user or
                not self.context.get("request").user.is_admin_role):
            self.fields.pop("deleted")

    def get_deleted(self, obj):
        return bool(obj.deleted)
```

In general it works fine. But I found a specific situation which cause weird error.

There are two applications `users` and `companies`. First one have `UserBankAccount` model, second one have `CompanyBankAccount` model.
In the `users/serializers.py` I have:

```
class AbstractBankAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    public_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'id',
            'bank_name',
            'account_name',
            'owner_name',
            'bic',
            'iban',
            'public_name',
        ]

    def get_public_name(self, obj):
        return obj.public_name

class UserBankAccountSerializer(AbstractBankAccountSerializer):
    """Serialize data from the UserBankAccount."""

    class Meta(AbstractBankAccountSerializer.Meta):
        model = UserBankAccount
```

`UserBankAccount` doesn't inherit from `SoftDeleteModel` and do not have  `deleted` field.

But the `CompanyBankAccount` inherits from `SoftDeleteModel`.
So I use my serializer with custom metaclass there.
`companies/serialziers.py`:

```
class CompanyBankAccountSerializer(SoftDeletionSerializer, AbstractBankAccountSerializer):
    class Meta(AbstractBankAccountSerializer.Meta):
        model = CompanyBankAccount
```

And that's where the problems starts. Now whenever I'm trying to use `UserBankAccountSerializer` I get weird errors exactly one time after the call.
For example this code:

```
serialzier=UserBankAccountSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    ...
```

will raise an error
`ImproperlyConfigured('Field name`deleted`is not valid for model`UserBankAccount`.',)`
But if I place `ipdb` there and run it first (it generates an erorr), then I run it one more time and it returns `True` as expected.

I tried to use `mro` to check

`ipdb> serializer.__class__.mro()`

`[<class 'apps.bankaccounts.serializers.UserBankAccountSerializer'>, <class 'apps.bankaccounts.serializers.AbstractBankAccountSerializer'>, <class 'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer'>, <class 'rest_framework.serializers.Serializer'>, <class 'rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer'>, <class 'rest_framework.fields.Field'>, <class 'object'>]`

But no trace of the `SoftDeletionSerializer`.

The thing is that if I remove `SoftDeletionSerializer` from the `CompanyBankAccountSerializer` - than everything works, no errors in the `UserBankAccountSerializer`.
It seems like somehow metaclass used in the `SoftDeletionSerializer` affects the `UserBankAccountSerializer` via `AbstractBankAccountSerializer`, but I can't get why this happening and how I can avoid this.

I also tried to catch an error and print it fully with `traceback`. Here what I get

```
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/projects/project/companies/views.py", line 83, in add_bank_account
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 236, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 434, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 458, in to_internal_value
    fields = self._writable_fields
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 369, in _writable_fields
    field for field in self.fields.values()
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 362, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1021, in get_fields
    source, info, model, depth
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1166, in build_field
    return self.build_unknown_field(field_name, model_class)
File "/home/user/projects/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1278, in build_unknown_field
    (field_name, model_class.__name__)
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestion why this happening and how it can be avoided (apart from removing metaclass and abstract serializier model)

Thanks in advance .